# KVKCalendar Does not comform to protocol CalendarDataSource

Tags: ios, swift, calendar, protocols

I am trying to use KVKCaldendar, however I am getting the 'Does not conform to protocol' error when trying to use the CalendarDataSource.

Here is my extension:

```
extension JobDetailsViewController: CalendarDataSource {
func eventsForCalendar() -> [Event] {
    return self.events
}    
}
```

Here is where I create my calendar:

```
private lazy var calendarView: CalendarView = {
    var style = Style()
    if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
        style.month.isHiddenSeporator = true
        style.timeline.widthTime = 40
        style.timeline.offsetTimeX = 2
        style.timeline.offsetLineLeft = 2
    } else {
        style.timeline.widthEventViewer = 500
    }
    style.timeline.startFromFirstEvent = false
    style.followInInterface = true
    style.timeline.offsetTimeY = 80
    style.timeline.offsetEvent = 3
    style.timeline.currentLineHourWidth = 40
    style.allDay.isPinned = true
    style.startWeekDay = .sunday
    style.timeHourSystem = .twelveHour

    let calendar = CalendarView(frame: view.frame, date: selectDate, style: style)
    calendar.dataSource = self
    return calendar
}()
```

The weird thing is if I create a new project that only had the KVKCalendar pod, it seems to work ok, but in the project I am actually wanting to use it in I get this error. What could the cause be?

Entire ViewController file:

```
import UIKit
import KVKCalendar

class JobDetailsViewController: UIViewController {

    var jobKeyStr: String?
var login = LoginResponseModel.getLogin()
var events = [Event]()

@IBOutlet weak var calendarFrame: UIView!

private lazy var selectDate: Date = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
    return formatter.date(from: "14.12.2018") ?? Date()
}()

private lazy var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl = {
    let array: [CalendarType]
    if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
        array = CalendarType.allCases
    } else {
        array = CalendarType.allCases.filter({ $0 != .year })
    }
    let control = UISegmentedControl(items: array.map({ $0.rawValue.capitalized }))
    control.tintColor = .red
    control.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
    control.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switchCalendar), for: .valueChanged)
    return control
}()

private lazy var calendarView: CalendarView = {
    var style = Style()
    if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
        style.month.isHiddenSeporator = true
        style.timeline.widthTime = 40
        style.timeline.offsetTimeX = 2
        style.timeline.offsetLineLeft = 2
    } else {
        style.timeline.widthEventViewer = 500
    }
    style.timeline.startFromFirstEvent = false
    style.followInInterface = true
    style.timeline.offsetTimeY = 80
    style.timeline.offsetEvent = 3
    style.timeline.currentLineHourWidth = 40
    style.allDay.isPinned = true
    style.startWeekDay = .sunday
    style.timeHourSystem = .twelveHour

    let calendar = CalendarView(frame: view.frame, date: selectDate, style: style)
//        calendar.delegate = self
    calendar.dataSource = self
    return calendar
}()

@objc func switchCalendar(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    let type = CalendarType.allCases[sender.selectedSegmentIndex]
    calendarView.set(type: type, date: selectDate)
    calendarView.reloadData()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
    } else {
        view.backgroundColor = .white
    }
    calendarView.set(type: .year, date: Date())
    self.calendarFrame.addSubview(calendarView)
    navigationItem.titleView = segmentedControl
    getJobSchedule()
}


}

extension JobDetailsViewController: CalendarDataSource {
func eventsForCalendar() -> [Event] {
    return events
}
}

    extension JobDetailsViewController {
    func createEvents(completion: ([Event]) -> Void) {
    //        let models = // Get events from storage / API
        var events = [Event]()

        //for model in models {
            var event = Event()
    //            event.id = model.id
//            event.start = model.startDate // start date event
//            event.end = model.endDate // end date event
//            event.color = model.color
//            event.isAllDay = model.allDay
//            event.isContainsFile = !model.files.isEmpty
//
//            // Add text event (title, info, location, time)
//            if model.allDay {
//                event.text = "\(model.title)"
//            } else {
//                event.text = "\(startTime) - \(endTime)\n\(model.title)"
//            }
            events.append(event)
        //}
        completion(events)
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe some updation issue contains on that library - Check this link some person already raised the same issue on there - https://github.com/kvyatkovskys/KVKCalendar/issues/51. So you must wait for their fixes.

Comment: @Ram that's actually me, haha. I posted in both to see where I get the answer first...

Comment: Your code works fine, I just imported KVKCalendar into a project and used your code as-is except changing the `self.events` and `selectDate` references.  Have you tried cleaning your project(Product->Clean Build Folder, and run again holding option)?  Or have you tried deleting the Derived Data for the project(Xcode->Preferences->Locations, click the arrow for 'Derived Data' and delete the folder)?

Comment: @clawesome Yes I have done that. Several times because I literally have no clue what else to do.

Comment: @clawesome I have also removed the pod and cleaned the project, then re-added it, and cleaned again. Closed XCode, restarted the macbook, etc...

Comment: @linuxer are you 100% sure that you're adding the `calendarView` property to `JobDetailsViewController`?  Not sure what else it could be.  I could look at the project if you need.

Comment: @clawesome I am sure. If I don't set the datasource, I am able to run and see the calendar. I just can't add events. If this wasn't a work project I would have you look at it. So, thanks for the offer. I am really stuck. If I go to a different branch of the project it works. Is it possible that there's another pod or something that is breaking it?

Comment: @clawesome I added all the code in that file to the post. Let me know if you see anything that looks off. I hopefully removed anything proprietary.

Comment: @linuxer are you using multiple calendar libraries?  If that's the case `CalendarDataSource` could have an ambiguous definition, but I would think Xcode would warn you of that.  You could trying specifying the pod for the explicit inheritance: `extension JobDetailsViewController: KVKCalendar.CalendarDataSource { ... }` and `private lazy var calendarView: KVKCalendar.CalendarView = { ... }`

Comment: @clawesome I had been trying several calendar libraries to find one I like, but had removed all of them. I don't get any warnings about it. Just tried specifying anyway, just to see. No difference

Comment: The code you posted, you can't build and get past the error the `.datasource = self` not uncommented?  Or are you trying to use the commented `.delegate = self`?  If it's the former, try casting the controller as the a CalendarDataSource delegate: `calendar.dataSource = self as! CalendarDataSource`.  That should get you past the error, but no idea why you'd be getting the error to begin with as the code built fine for me.

Comment: @clawesome Right, I cannot build at all, with that first snippet of code where I am using the extension for the datasource. The only way it builds is to not do anything with the datasource. This is driving me crazy. I don't know what else to do except create a new project, and move the files over and see if it ever breaks, or just works. I tried starting from scratch with the calendar in another file (same project) doesn't work. I create a completely new project and it works. There is just something off with this project. But no clue what

Comment: @clawesome Something interesting. I have also be looking at the sample provided be the developer. I can build even if I don't have the eventsForCalendar method in the extension. But I can't build in my project if I don't have the method there.

Comment: Have you tried letting Xcode fix the error?  When errors come up and have a red circle with a white center, you can click it and Xcode will ask if you want to add the protocol stubs.  Trying deleting the `eventsForCalendar` method and seeing if Xcode gives you the option.  There's also a keyboard shortcut to letting Xcode fix the errors, it's control+option+command+F.

Comment: @clawesome I did that right away, thinking I had just mistyped something. Still shows the error. I did seem to find a work around though. If I copy all the files into my project instead of using the pod it seems to work. So I am guessing the pod is corrupt or something.

Comment: Have you tried clearing out the pod completely from your system?  https://gist.github.com/mbinna/4202236

Comment: @clawesome Thank you very much. That seems to be the real solution. It works from the pod now.

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear it.